# How to parse a delimited column of a CSV file and make them be part of CSV file by Python

Tags: python, csv, delimited

I have a CSV file with the following format/content and would like to see an easier way to further parse the col3 content (delimited) to include them to CSV file by using python.

I'm new to this and the simple looping approach should be working but I would like to know any easier and faster way to implement this.

From:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4 
1,"David","Job=Sales Manager;Hobby=reading;Sex=Male","31"
2,"Mary","Job=Nurse;Hobby=hiking;Sex=Female","23"
```

to:

```
col1,col2,Job,Hobby,Sex,col4 
1,"David","Sales Manager","reading","Male","31"
2,"Mary","Nurse","hiking","Female","23"
```

Comment: @Patryk Please don't change the formatting of the OP's data. They never said there are spaces between fields.

Comment: Provide code that shows what you mean by "simple looping approach" that "should" be working and what you think is wrong with it, your questions is too ambiguous and possibly opinion-based as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` library which helps deal with tabular data in a pretty easy way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("xxx.csv")

new_df = pd.concat([df.drop('col3', axis=1), 
                    df.col3.apply(lambda s: pd.Series(dict(tuple(p.split('=')) for p in s.split(";"))))], 
                    axis=1)
```

[image]

To write out as `.csv`, simply call `to_csv()`: `new_df.to_csv("newXXX.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple class base approach with a parse function and an output function.

```
import csv

class Person:

    def __init__(self, string):
        self.attributes = {}
        data = string.split(",")
        self.attributes["id"] = data[0]
        self.attributes["name"] = data[1]
        self.attributes["age"] = data[3]

        self.parse_data(data[2])

    def parse_data(self, data):
        for attr in data.split(";"):
            entry = attr.split("=")
            self.attributes[entry[0]] = entry[1]

    def return_data(self):
        return ','.join(self.attributes.values())

input = '''1,"David","Job=Sales Manager;Hobby=reading;Sex=Male","31"
2,"Mary","Job=Nurse;Hobby=hiking;Sex=Female","23"'''

people = []

for line in input.split("\n"):
    person = Person(line)
    people.append(person)

print(','.join(people[0].attributes.keys())) # print the keys

for person in people:
    print(person.return_data()) # print the data
```

Lightweight (and relatively easy to use), I left reading an writing of csv files out of it. This will return the columns in a consistent format. You will notice however some punctuation that hasn't been taken care of. That can be easily fixed too.

Let me know if this approach works for you.